# kartik yii2 export showing "Call to a member function getModels() on array" while exporting the data

Tags: yii2, export-to-excel, kartik-v

I need to export the data using "kartik yii2 export",but its showing "Call to a member function getModels() on array" error.
Actually I'm trying to fetch the data from multiple tables.And while printing the data,its showing everything as i need,but whenever I click to export again the error is throwing.
Also kartik yii2 export is working fine with single table.
Please help to solve this.

Comment: It's obvious as it says, you are supplying an array where you need to provide an object, add your relevant code which is used in the above scenario.

Comment: You are probably trying to pass the array somewhere where `yii\data\DataProviderInterface` is expected. Try wrapping your array into [`yii\data\ArrayDataProvider`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider)

Comment: Thanks for comments..
Let me try with php excel import option.